# Create a blank google drive file, force to open with third party app

Tags: google-drive-api, mime-types

I am trying to create a file that will open with Lucidchart 3rd party app(already installed on my drive).

I set mimeType, defaultOpenUrl, etc. but the  created file has mime-type of the app that created it.

For example if I try to do it from drive api explorer, it will set the mime type to mimeType of explorer app.

Any solutions to this problem?

Answer (score 0):

No, only an app is allowed to create files with that app's app-specific MIME type. You can use the create url from the app resource associated with the app to ask it to create a file.  See [Apps resource](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/apps#resource).

Comment: I am trying to create a blank Lucidchart file on google drive, store the fileID to the database, and open the file in edit mode(redirect to the new created file).

Comment: Yes, I know that, but that won't solve my problem, since I have to sync the file id later. By Calling insert file I can get the fileID immediately, hence no syncing is needed. Is it the only way to link the file after creation, what do you think?